Is it allowed to define a set of points like x ∈ [0,y]?
I imagine this as 0≤x≤y mapping all the points (x,y) where x≥0 and the point lies below or on the line y=x, but I am not sure I am allowed to write it like this.
I want to write it like this to easily define areas, especially being able to use intersections and unions.
i.e. Points (x,y) plotted on the region marked by an annulus with radial lower bound r and and upper bound R would look something like this:
x^2 ∈ [r^2-y^2,R^2-y^2]
or even x^2+y^2 ∈ [r^2,R^2] which would simply look like r^2≤x^2+y^2≤R^2 with inequalities.
or with unions as an example, I can define the first 1/8 slice of the annulus (from 0 to pi/4) described above by intersecting it with x ∈ [0,y]:
x^2 ∈ [r^2-y^2,R^2-y^2]∩[0,y]
or even the first and fourth 1/8 slice as:
x^2 ∈ [r^2-y^2,R^2-y^2]∩[0,|y|]
and so on...
Wondering if this is possible, thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$0 \le x \le y$ means that $x \in [0,y]$ as there is no assumption done on $y$, apart that it is greater than $x$. Furthermore, $0 \le x \le y$ is not a set, it is a statement between real variables that could be used to build a set. Also, this condition is rather for points that are above the line $x=y$ (make a draw and pick some points to see it).
The set you want to describe should be written as $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y \le x\}$. If you only want the "upper-right" quadrant, you may transform it into $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, 0\le y \le x\}$. This latter set can also be written as an intersection of two sets. Formally, a set, or rather a subset in our case, is defined by two main elements, written between brackets :

We have to define what are the used variables, here $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
We have to define condition(s) on these variables that will build our set, here $y \le x$.

Then, $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y \le x\}$ can be understood as the set of all points of the real plane such that the $y$ coordinate is lower than the $x$ one.

Awesome! Thanks for the quick answer. How would you write an intersection or union. For example how would I write the point (x,y) in this area link into one set notation with unions

Either you write ${ ... } \cup { ... } \cup { ... }\cup { ... }$ where each bracket is filled with the definition of one "wing" or in single brackets with $or$ bewteen each conidition for each subregions.
